# Converting java 8 lambda expression to work in java 7

Tags: java, lambda

Trying to convert the this section of code to get rid of the lambda expressions so it'll be able to work in java 7

```
System.out.println(nicksGraph.findPath(nicksGraph.nodeWith(new Coordinate(0,0)), (a->a.getX()==3 && a.getY()==1), new PriorityQueue<Node<Coordinate>, Integer>(funcTotal)));
```

I've looked around but maybe I'm just not understanding it correctly.

Comment: there may be many ways, I think the simplest is just to write a function and call it instead of the lambda expression

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Java 8, a lambda expression is a substitute for an anonymous inner class that implements a functional interface.  It looks like here you're using a `Predicate`, because the expression is a `boolean`.

The [`Predicate` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) was introduced in Java 8, so you need to re-create it yourself.  You will not be able to create `default` or `static` methods, so just keep the functional interface method.

```
public interface Predicate<T>
{
    public boolean test(T t);
}
```

Then, replace the lambda expression with the anonymous class declaration.

```
System.out.println(nicksGraph.findPath(
    nicksGraph.nodeWith(new Coordinate(0,0)),
    // Replacement anonymous inner class here.
    new Predicate<Coordinate>() {
       @Override
       public boolean test(Coordinate a) {
          // return the lambda expression here.
          return a.getX()==3 && a.getY()==1;
       }
    },
    new PriorityQueue<Node<Coordinate>, Integer>(funcTotal)));
```

Answer (score 3):

findPath requires a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) as second argument. You could replace the lambda with

```
 new Predicate<>(){
     public boolean test(Integer i){
          return a.getX() == 3 && a.getY() == 1;
     }
 }
```

But the main problem will simply be the availability of `Predicate` itself, since it's a java8 feature. this code won't run in java7, no matter if you use lambdas or not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda). 
It is a backport of Java 8's lambda expressions to Java 7, 6 and 5.

> Just as there was Retroweaver et al. for running Java 5 code with
>   generics on Java 1.4, Retrolambda lets you run Java 8 code with lambda
>   expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements on
>   Java 7, 6 or 5. It does this by transforming your Java 8 compiled
>   bytecode so that it can run on an older Java runtime