# How to translate java 8's lambda to java 7?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In Java 8 we have lambdas like this one

```
a.sort((v1, v2) -> {});
```

How would this functionality be implemented in Java 7?

Comment: I think you are talking about java 8

Comment: yes...but it dould be heplful if somebody translate to me in java 7 :)

Comment: If I recall, the `->` operator in java is essentially part of the syntax for a new lambda expression. It was introduced in java 8, but I didn't know it was available in 7.

Comment: Here is a nice detailed explanation of the sort syntax (aka lambda) in Java 8. http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the question, he wants to see how it would be implemented in java 7 I think? He could use better english, for sure.

Comment: Wait, this compiles??? Please post a full example as I can't make this work.

Comment: Tunaki see my answer. The example won't compile in it's current form as the expression needs to return an integer value (-1, 0 or 1 respectively).

Comment: [Converting java 8 lambda expression to work in java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108963/converting-java-8-lambda-expression-to-work-in-java-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 differences between Java 7 and 8 relevant to this question.

1. In Java 7, `List` did not have a `sort` method. You had to use `Collections.sort`.
2. In Java 7, lambda expressions ( `->` ) were not part of the language.

The Java 7 equivalent is

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
        // Write what you need here.     
    }
});
```

Comment: Somebody just downvoted all 4 answers. Why?

Comment: Sometimes I read on meta that people downvote answers to discourage people from answer bad questions. Although this isn't the worst of questions, it might be the case here

Comment: That's fair enough but the question has since been edited and all supplied answers fit the brief. A bit harsh in my book, there are better ways to go about it surely?

Comment: Agreed. I edited the question to be more readable and understandable, and the answers to apply to the question. However we will probably never know who or why downvoted the answers. Don't worry about it and just move on :-)

Answer (score 2):

It basically translates to this:

```java
a.sort(new Comparator<T>(){
    public int compare(T v1, T v2){
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Java 8 introduced the "lambda" concept which allows you to eliminate the anonymous subclass syntax (among other things). You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 1):

The short-hand lambda expression syntax introduced in Java 8 roughly represents the following in Java 7:

```
a.sort(new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object v1, Object v2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that I don't know the types of `v1` and `v2`, so I generalized them to `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can use lambda expressions in place of a Comparator to sort collections. Traditionally you'd either implement the Comparable interface for the class you where going to sort and override the compareTo method to show how the objects would be sorted or call Collections.sort passing in your collection and a new Comparator.

I'm java 8 you can use a lambda expressions in its place. This example has two objects v1 and v2. In your example there is no implementation as to how these objects should then be compared.

EDIT:

An example

Java 8:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
ArrayList<TestClass> a = new ArrayList<>();
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    TestClass t = new TestClass();
    t.setValue(r.nextInt());
    a.add(t);
}

System.out.println("Before sort.");
a.sort((v1, v2) -> { return Integer.compare( v1.getValue(), v2.getValue()); });
a.forEach( x -> System.out.println("Value: " + x.getValue()));
```

Is equivalent to (in Java 7):

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
ArrayList<TestClass> a = new ArrayList<>();
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    TestClass t = new TestClass();
    t.setValue(r.nextInt());
    a.add(t);
}

System.out.println("Before sort.");
Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<TestClass>(){
    public int compare(TestClass x, TestClass y) {
        return Integer.compare(x.getValue(), y.getValue());
    }

});
for(TestClass x : a){
    System.out.println("Value: " + x.getValue());
}
```

As you can see, Lambda expressions can considerably cut down on the number of lines of code required.